# Cloaking url but keeping sub-urls

Tags: html, url, cloaking

I have a dot-tk ([www.dot.tk](http://www.dot.tk)) domain that redirects to a blog of mine.
But I have a problem. If a visitor of the blog who have entered through the tk-redirection, navigates to a specific post or even follows a link that leads elsewhere, then the URL-bar doesn't change to reflect the change. It always show the tk-address only. I want sub-urls to be visible so that the visitor can copy and send the url of that post to a friend or even bookmark the specific post.
This does works well if the reader has entered the blog from the normal url.
One "solution" to this would be to put this code in the blog:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">if (top!=self) top.location.href=self.location.href;</script>
</head>
```

With this code the real url will always be seen, not the tk-url, even if the visitor have entered through the tk-url.
This works, but preferably I would like to show the tk-adress AND the sub-urls, if possible.

In other words...

Instead of **http://myblog.blogspot.com** it should be **www.myblog.tk**  (this works)

And instead of **http://myblog.blogspot.com/blogpost5** it should be **www.myblog.tk/blogpost5** (This is what I need help with, if it's possible somehow)

I hope I've made myself clear and I hope there's a solution to it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't want to use this redirection scheme. Instead use [Blogger's custom domain name functionality](http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55373).

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I followed the link you provided and managed to get www.bloggan.tk to work correctly.
However, bloggan.tk without the www does not work as it says it should.
It gives:
"Google    Error
Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server."

Am I using the correct settings? Here's an image of my settings in dot.tk:
http://yfrog.com/jabloggantkdottkp

And in the blogger settings there's a checkbox saying:
Redirect bloggan.tk to www.bloggan.tk

I've checked it but it doesn't seem to make any changes? Or maybe it just takes more time?

Thanks!